# Fill form with values from DB in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a form with the following logic:

```
TextField name = new TextField<>("name", Model.of(""));
TextField surname = new TextField<>("surname", Model.of(""));
TextField mobile = new TextField<>("mobile", Model.of(""));
TextField phone = new TextField<>("phone", Model.of(""));
HiddenField id = new HiddenField<>("id", Model.of(""));
EmailTextField email = new EmailTextField("email", Model.of(""));

Form form = new Form("formContact") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit() {
        super.onSubmit();

        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setName(name.getValue());
        contact.setEmail(email.getValue());
        contact.setSurname(surname.getValue());
        contact.setMobile(mobile.getValue());
        contact.setPhone(phone.getValue());

        service.save(contact);
    }
};

form.add(id);
form.add(email.setRequired(false));
form.add(name.setRequired(true));
form.add(surname.setRequired(true));
form.add(mobile.setRequired(true));
form.add(phone.setRequired(false));

add(form);
```

I use that code when a client wants to insert a new `Contact`, and it works.

What I need now is to handle the `update` of an existing `Contact`, so I just need to fill an existing form with values from a known `Contact` instance:

`Contact contact = service.get(1);`

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use CompoundPropertyModel for form so it will update when model is changing and also don't need set data to fields. Send model when you creating page or model, you can send contract instance(even empty one). Let's say your class name is MyPanel, then constructor

```
MyPanel(String id, IModel<Contract> model) {
    super(id, model);
}
```

Now when you are creating form you can use CompoundPropertyModel benefits(in Contract class should be fields name, surname, mobile,etc with public getters and setters)

```
@Override
protected void onInitialize() {
super.onInitialize();

Form<Contract> form = new Form("formContact", new CompoundPropertyModel(getModel()){
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit() {
        super.onSubmit();
        service.save(getModelObject());
    }
});
add(form);
form.add(new TextField<>("name").setRequired(true));
form.add(new TextField<>("surname").setRequired(true));
form.add(new TextField<>("mobile").setRequired(true));
form.add(new TextField<>("phone").setRequired(false));
form.add(new HiddenField<>("id"));
form.add(new EmailTextField("email").setRequired(false));
```

Let's update contract by button clicking

```
form.add(new AjaxLink<Void>("updateContract"){

    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        form.setModelObject(service.get(1));
        target.add(form);  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the existing contact's data in the models of the form components.

E.g. `TextField name = new TextField<>("name", new PropertyModel(contact, "name"));`

Also see CompoundPropertyModel.